# Base table vs Polymorphic relationships database design

Tags: database-design, architecture

I have the following classes:

```
User (can have many businesses, franchises and posts)

Business (belongs to a user - can belong to MANY users at the same time, has many galleries)
Franchise (belongs to a user - can belong to MANY users at the same time)
Post (belongs to one user, has many galleries)

Gallery (belongs to one business or post, has many media)
Media (belongs to one gallery)
```

I want to design a good database for this data and I can think of two options:

1. (Bass table approach) Create tables for each of these classes, and extra tables 'entities' and 'user_entity' and make each of Business, Franchise and Post an 'entity' and then link users to entities through the user_entity table and finally add an entity_id on galleries table to indicate the owner of each gallery.
2. (Polymorphic approach) Create tables for each of these classes, and extra tables 'user_business' and 'user_franchise' to link users to the businesses and franchises they own. Also have a user_id field on the posts table to link each post to a user. Finally have gallery_owner_id and gallery_owner_type fields on the galleries table where id would link to either business or page id and type would be the class name of the gallery owner.

The system is expected to grow in the future.
Which of these approaches would be better? Why? Maybe there is another option I have not considered?

Any info or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the known risks at this point?  Are the relationships between entities likely to change?  Will you be in a prototype phase of development for a while or will you immediately have production data that you'd have to migrate if your schema changed?

Just trying to get a sense of what trade-offs are in play.

Comment: At this stage I am in development and will remain in development for quite some time. No production data. Any data in the databases during development (besides a few tables like uk_postcodes) can be wiped at any time without any consequences.